# Wakanda and SSL: Server Name and how to gracefully handle HTTP requests?

Tags: ssl, wakanda

I am running Wakanda Enterprise Studio/Server v10, and [the documentation](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Server-Reference-Guide/Administrating-Wakanda-Server/Configuring-secure-connections-SSLTLS.300-952181.en.html) for setting up SSL shows the use of the below command to generate the Private Key and Certificate Signing Request:

`openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myServer.key -out myServer.csr`

The document says to use the name of my server for `myServer`- is that the Domain Name?

Secondly, I'd like to gracefully handle HTTP requests. Can you suggest a strategy for this? It'd be nice to handle any requests to `http://example.com` by redirecting them to `https://example.com` so the upgrade is transparent to our users.

I had the idea of using my request handler (which just is used to log IPs now), to redirect. I am not sure yet how I would code that but if that sounds like a good strategy then I will pursue that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further down in the [documentation](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda/0.Beta/Configuring-secure-connections-SSLTLS.300-952181.en.html) it says the files should be named `cert.pem` and `key.pem`

> If you want to use the SSL/TLS protocol in your Wakanda application, the following files must be installed:
>   * key.pem: This file contains the private key.
>   If necessary, rename your private key file name manually to "key.pem".
>   * cert.pem: This file contains the certificate.
>   It must be named "cert.pem" and be in PKCS format. If you get a file in a different format, you must convert it into .pem format (see above).

---

You **will** need a CSR for either path, self signed or an official Certificate Authority.

After issuing the `openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myServer.key -out myServer.csr` command you will be presented numerous questions from `OpenSSL` that will be used for the CSR, one of those questions is the ServerName:

[image]

Comment: Thank you; I probably should have specified that I am interested in working with a Certificate Authority rather than using a self-signed certificate, so I would still need to generate the .csr as far as I understand.

Comment: you must generate a CSR either way - self signed or not. The CSR is what defines the server name. [This guide](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO13985) shows that after issuing the `openssl` command you will be asked multiple questions for the CSR, one of which is the ServerName

Comment: Gotcha-- thank you for linking the guide, I am done for the day and will read/watch it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I wanted to follow up and say thanks again. I used openssl to generate a private key and a self-signed certificate- for testing. And it is working with my Wakanda Solution properly. Now that I've made it this far and get what is going on, I'll move ahead with contacting a certificate authority.

Comment: @NAMS Did you ever figure out the best way to gracefully handle HTTP requests?

Comment: @JeffG we decided to use a firewall rule to redirect to HTTPS.